# Where does T come from in this derivation?

Tags: notation

In equation 4 of this paper [http://graphics.stanford.edu/~smr/ICP/comparison/eggert_comparison_mva97.pdf](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Esmr/ICP/comparison/eggert_comparison_mva97.pdf),
the length-squared term is expanded, from
$$\sum_{i}^N \| d_{c_{i}} - R m_{c_{i}} \| ^ 2 $$

to
$$ \sum_{i}^N (d_{c_{i}}^T d_{c_{i}} + m_{c_{i}}^T m_{c_{i}} - 2 d_{c_{i}}^T R m_{c_{i}} )$$

$d_{c_{i}}$ and $m_{c_{i}}$ are simple 3d vectors, R is a 3x3 matrix.

What is the T symbol, and why does it appear here when vector values are squared?

I understand the rest of the paper itself, it's just this one line that I don't get.

Thanks

Comment: $v^T$ is the transposed of the vector $v$. That is, if $v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\\vdots\\v_n\end{pmatrix}$, then $$v^T=\begin{pmatrix}v_1 & \cdots&v_n\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I see, but then what significance does transposing a 1D vector have? Is it just a formality to make it consistent with matrix multiplication?
If we were to consider multiplying many vector terms at once, would every second term be implied to be transposed, automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, $v\mapsto v^T$ is a linear map $M_{1,n}\mathbb R\rightarrow M_{n,1}\mathbb R$, where $M_{k,j}\mathbb R$ is the vector space of $k\times j$ matrixes (that is, $k$ rows and $j$ columns), sending the $1\times n$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\\vdots\\v_n\end{pmatrix}$$to the $n\times 1$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}v_1&\cdots&v_n\end{pmatrix}$$ by definition of matrix multiplication, $$v^Tv=\left(v_1^2+\cdots+v_n^2\right)=(\|v\|^2)$$ so $v^Tv$ is a $1\times1$-matrix and is identified with $\|v\|^2$. In general, for every pair $v,w$, the scalar $w^Tv$ is equal to the canonical scalar product $w\cdot v$ on $\mathbb R^n$.

In the case of $1$-dimensional vectors, then transposing have no significance, since it reduces to the identity $M_{1,1}\mathbb R\rightarrow M_{1,1}\mathbb R$.

Regarding the multiplication of multiple vectors, it's not something you'll find usually (at least, I've never seen a product of more than two vectors, which is the scalar product).